# Boolean formula for graph 3COL

Tags: graphs, satisfiability, boolean-algebra, colorings

For a given undirected graph $G=(V,E)$ I'm trying to construct a boolean polynomially computable formula $\varphi$ with the following property: $\varphi$ is satisfiable $\iff$ vertices of $G$ can be colored in $3$ colors with the following condition: For any edge $(u, v)\in E$, if $u$ and $v$ have different colors, then there exists $w\in V$ such that $(u, w)\in E$, $(v, w)\in E$, and $w$ has the third color (different from both $u$ and $v$). Here it is ok that two vertices of the same color may be connected by an edge.

Comment: Are you looking for a coloring in the standard sense? I.e., the endpoints of each edge must  have different colors?

Comment: @Steven Not in the traditional sense, two endpoints of edge may have the same color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one possible formula: $\texttt{true}$.
Indeed, every graph admits a coloring that satisfies your requirements: simply color all vertices with the same color.

Comment: Thanks. But if we color all vertices with the same color, the condition "For any edge $(u, v)\in E$, if $u$ and $v$ have different colors, there exists..." never happens?

Comment: That condition because trivially true since there are no edges $(u,v)$ that satisfy the requirements. Essentially, you are using an universal quantifier over an empty set.